# How to draw a pattern in Win8 Task Manager like attached image?

Tags: windows, taskmanager

[image]

This is very interesting.
How does it implement? In code? or what else?

Comment: lol...both images are impossibly based on real profiling data. It's a hoax, or a data injection trick.

Comment: Clearly a hoax. Note that the graph does not match the miniature on the left hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer:

Case 1) You want to draw an image into the task manager app from another app: you cannot do this since it is not possible to control a different app that way (well, it *might* be possible using very low level techniques like DDI, API hooking and whatnot, but these are just hacks and might not work in Win8 anyway).

Case 2) You want to create a system load such that the CPU graphs results in an image as you have shown here. This is not possible because the graph is a time graph, hence the horizontal positioning is always a constant time and only going forward (to the right). Your image would require to go backwards in time. Hence: impossible.

Mike